# Adding AGOL users from an other organisation without losing own Mobile Worker license

Tags: arcgis-online, license, arcgis-field-maps, arcgis-experience-builder

Is it possible to add a group of contractors to my organisation without using our Mobile Worker licenses - they have all required accounts and licenses already? So in brief, group of contractors will work with our data but will use their own AGOL/mobile worker license.

As a part of workflow we will be using Experience Builder to provide some management capabilities to the contractors.

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible, but also probably not necessary. You could create a Group on your organisation, add the content and maps etc. to it, then invite those users to join that Group from their own organisation.